# find sum of amount for group of list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Reactjs.

I have below data

```
Name        Amount

Poorna     11000.00

Kumar       2900.00

Ashok       20000.00

Kumar      3020.00

Poorna     15000.00
```

Output should display like below

```
Name        Amount

Poorna     26000.00

Kumar       5920.00

Ashok       20000.00
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce()`

```
var sample= [
   {  Name: 'Poorna', Amount: 50},
   {  Name: 'Kumar', Amount: 50},
   {  Name: 'Ashok ', Amount: 75},
   {  Name: 'Poorna', Amount: 35},
   
];
var res = sample.reduce((a, obj)=>{
  var existItem = a.find(item => item.Name=== obj.Name);
  if(existItem){
    existItem.Amount += obj.Amount;
    return a;
  } 
  a.push(obj);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: when i add in my app this logic i am getting values like below.
amount: "110001500015000", instead of adding it is getting concatenated.

Comment: I think typing your Amount is a string..Try to turn it into a number with parseInt

Comment: myArray = sample.map(function(obj) {
    return {Amount: parseInt(obj.Amount), Name: obj.Name};
});

Comment: Now use the myArray in res instead of the sample

Comment: Thanks now it worked,
0: {amount: 26000, name: "Poorna"}
1: {amount: 5920, name: "Kumar"}
2: {amount: 20000, name: "Dada"}
now i wanted to access amount and name. I tried res.name and res.amount. i got output as undefined. could you please help to access this fields.

Comment: you can use foreach or map-->`var name=res.map(item=>item.Name) ;var Amount=res.map(item=>item.Amoun)  `

Comment: `console.log(name)`==>["Poorna", "Kumar", "Ashok "]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can group the data according to names:

```js
let data = [
  {name: "Poorna", salary:11000.0},
  {name: "Kumar",salary: 2900.0},
  {name: "Ashok", salary:20000.0},
  {name: "Kumar", salary:3020.0},
  {name: "Poorna", salary:15000.0},
];

let sol = {};

for (let a of data) {
  if (sol[a.name]) {
sol[a.name] += a.salary;
  } else {
sol[a.name] = a.salary;
  }
}

console.log(sol);
```

Here is full react app:

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
let data = [
  { name: "Poorna", salary: 11000.0 },
  { name: "Kumar", salary: 2900.0 },
  { name: "Ashok", salary: 20000.0 },
  { name: "Kumar", salary: 3020.0 },
  { name: "Poorna", salary: 15000.0 }
];
export default function App() {
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState(data);
  const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);

  const groupData = () => {
    let sol = {};

    for (let a of initialData) {
      if (sol[a.name]) {
        sol[a.name] += a.salary;
      } else {
        sol[a.name] = a.salary;
      }
    }
    setGroup(sol);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    groupData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          {" "}
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        {initialData.map(d => (
          <tr>
            {" "}
            <td>{d.name}</td>
            <td>{d.salary}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
      <h2>Grouped data</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        {group &&
          Object.keys(group).map(key => (
            <tr>
              <td>{key}</td>
              <td>{group[key]}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find the Working app here : [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s5dgcp?file=src/App.js)

Comment: i have objects with different names and in my array list there are multiple objects. I will to add logic based on objects.

Comment: useEffect will work when mount and unmount. I have filters in my screen in that scenario it is not calling. is there any replacement for useEffect.

Comment: you can always use dependencies for ```useEffect``` if you want to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce()`

```js
const array = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Poorna', amount: 11000 }, 
{ id: 2, name: 'Kumar', amount: 2900}, 
{ id: 3,  name: 'Ashok', amount: 20000},
{ id: 3,  name: 'Kumar', amount: 3020},
{ id: 3,  name: 'Poorna', amount: 15000}
];
    
 let output = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
     if (acc[curr.name]) acc[curr.name].amount += curr.amount;
     else acc[curr.name] = { ...curr };
     return acc;
    }, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a Map:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const list = [
    { name: 'Poorna', amount: 11000 },
    { name: 'Kumar', amount: 2900 },
    { name: 'Ashok', amount: 20000 },
    { name: 'Kumar', amount: 3020 },
    { name: 'Poorna', amount: 15000 }
  ];

  const map = new Map();
  list.forEach(({ name, amount }) => 
         map.set(name, map.has(name) ? map.get(name) + amount : amount));

  const listItems = [...map.entries()].map(([name, amount]) => <li>{name}: {amount}</li>);

  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below is the best way.

```js
const data = [
   {  Name: 'Poorna', Amount: 11000 },
   {  Name: 'Kumar', Amount: 2900 },
   {  Name: 'Ashok', Amount: 20000 },
   {  Name: 'Kumar', Amount: 3020 },
   {  Name: 'Poorna', Amount: 15000 },
];

const result = data.reduce((prev, { Name, Amount }) => {
  if (prev[Name]) return {...prev, [Name]: prev[Name] + Amount};
  return {...prev, [Name]: Amount};
}, {});
```

Comment: when I add above logic in my app, i got result like below.
Poorna: "1100015000", instead of adding it is concatinated

Comment: @bobaPoorna Make sure the value `Amount` is exactly the `number` type in your data. If not, use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to properly convert the type.